Laravel app server delays response with extra 10 seconds on the first request
I am having an issue with a server (actually multiple different servers) that host a Laravel app.
Infrastructure: The app is hosted at a couple of windows machines in AWS EC2 instance. The machines are good enough, so they do not run out of resources. They work ok. We expect huge load in a week or so, so I tried to set up a new instance to be able to hold the traffic. I set up a brand new instance as an absolute copy of one of the old ones - AMI, template, the whole deal. However, here comes the problem. The app works out of the box, but the first requests takes +10 seconds. The rest of the requests work fine. The machine is set up properly, confirmed with Amazon support, and the issue happens at localhost also - so not a networking issues. I have tried with both IIS server and the Laravel local server with artisan serve. The issue is the same. Here is the strange thing. If instead of returning the response, I dump the response with var_dump, then the first request takes 0.004 seconds instead of 10.004 seconds and then the next request takes +10 extra seconds. So the first return response from a controller is causing the issue. I tried all the stuff with IIS - disable recycling, auto-start, remove timeout and so on and so on. I removed all the middlewares, the DB is the same, the other instances work fine. I have cleaned the cache, not that also.
At this point I am out of ideas. Any insight would be great!

Maybe https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/first-query-really-slow?page=1&replyId=790468

its probably "boot request/cold start" where it initialize your app and load everything in memory/cache
vs subsequent request where things already cache and loaded in memory.
so when your app start (boot), there is something that slowing it down, be it internal function calls/implementation or external call. also check the storage sessions and logs dir, if you have so much in there, it can slow down your app boot time.

You can enable verbose logging in PHP to track initialization delays, and add simple profiling by logging request start and end times, especially in the middleware or controller layer.

It is not related to DB queries. Also logging requests start and end does not help. Basically the execution of the controller takes 0.004 seconds (logged it) and when I do return response()->json($json); it takes 10.004 sec. If I do var_dump($json) instead of return it takes 0.004 sec and then the next api call takes the extra 10 seconds

Is this for all requests even if you do a return response()->json([ 'test' => 'test' ]); ?
